# find id by traversing up to class

Tags: jquery

I want to find the id of the following.

```
    <div class="row" id="I_WANT_TO_FIND_THIS_CLASS">
        <div class="cell100">
            <div class="table">
                <div class="cell40 content label bordersRight borderBottom"><input class="inputField input270" type="text" name="Source1" value=""></div>
                <div class="cell15 content label bordersRight borderBottom"><input class="inputField input95" type="text" name="Date1" value=""></div>
                <div class="cell45 content label borderBottom"><input class="inputField input305" type="text" name="Result1" value=""></div>
                <div class="cell45 content label borderBottom"><INPUT type="button" value="x" onclick="removeRow(this)" /></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

this is my code that I tried. ( eventualy I want to delete the selected "row)"
There is a `removeRow(this)` button call on the 4th cell of the div

```
    function removeRow() {
        //$(this).closest('.row').remove();
        var div_id = $(this).closest('.row').attr('id');
        alert(div_id);
    }
```

Comment: I think more html is required to find solution. with what you are using closest()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are passing the clicked element reference as a parameter so change the method syntax to accept the parameter and then use that to find the `row` element

```
function removeRow(el) {
    //$(this).closest('.row').remove();
    var div_id = $(el).closest('.row').attr('id');
    alert(div_id);
}
```

Note: Since you are using jQuery, use jQuery event handlers instead of inline handlers

Answer (score 1):

You need object that is passed to `removeRow`, add parameter to `removeRow`, I added with name `source`. Use this `source` object instead of `this`.

[Live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6xaujfvo/)

```
function removeRow(source) {
     //$(this).closest('.row').remove();
     var div_id = $(source).closest('.row').attr('id');
     alert(div_id);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using `jQuery`. Try this.

```
$('input[type=button]').click(function(){
    div_id = $(this).closest('.row').attr('id');
    console.log($(this).closest('.row').attr('id'));
});
```